# How to save previous view and subviews state when you go back with backbone?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, pushstate, html5-history

View1 has a subview view1bis which opens onclick it doesn't go through the router to avoid unecessary routes and to avoid rendering view1 again (view1 is still visible while view1bis popup).
I click on some button on view1bis and it goes to view2 (using router).

I want to be able to click on some back button on view2 and come back to the previous state (which is view1 with viewe1bis menu opened or whatever selected on the previous page) Hope it's clear enough

I though about using the state object of the history api but:

If use this my route won't trigger.

```
window.history.pushState({wow:"test"}, null, '#screensaverGallery/'+path);
```

But if I use this I can't save th state object ({wow:"test"})

```
Backbone.history.navigate('#screensaverGallery/'+path, { trigger:true })
```

Any idea how I could handle this ? Is using the state object of the history api a good idea (I though it could fit), if not how would you handle this back state issue ?

Comment: Why would you need to save a state object?

Comment: View1 has a subview view1bis which opens onclick it doesn't go through the router to avoid unecessary routes and to avoid rendering view1 again (view1 is still visible while view1bis popup).
I click on some button on view1bis and it goes to view2 (using router). I want to be able to click on some back button on view2 and come back to the previous state (which is view1 with viewe1bis menu opened or whatever selected on the previous page)
Hope it's clear enough

Comment: Please update your question to ask help about this. As it stands now, this question is a classic case of the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: hmm ok. So you think using pushState is not a good solution for my problem ?

Comment: no idea ? why asking to change the question .. =/

Comment: Because an XY problem doesn't help anybody. You don't get good answers and it's useless for any other users.